# Programmatically choose which page to show first

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a Windows 8 Phone app where the user logs in using OAuth2. Once logged in, I can store their access and refresh tokens and use them to authenticate the user for future uses.

How do I choose which page to load first when the app is opened? I can check if an access token exists, and if it does, I would like to load the "profile" page. If it doesn't (i.e., if the user has never logged in, or logged out after the last session), then I need to show the login page.

I would like to show these pages as the **first** page when the user opens the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if your token exists in Isolated Storage and according to that navigate to one or another page.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    using (var folder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (folder.FileExists("SomeFileWithToken.txt"))
        {
            RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/ProfilePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

    }
}
```

Also, edit your manifest and clear the Navigation Page parameter in the Application UI tab

Or in code:

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name ="_default"/>
</Tasks>
```

Comment: When I try to clear the Navigation Page parameter in my manifest file, it doesn't let me keep it blank. Any ideas? For your alternative to that, where do I put the `<Tasks>`?

Comment: @user2515526 right click on manifest file and click 'View code'. Find the DefaultTask tag and remove NavigationPage property.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an `If` statement in the `Application_Launching` section in `App.xaml.cs`